# Is fs.mkdir() required to create a sub directory within /tmp in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Let's look at the code below. If I wanted to save a file to `/tmp/new_folder` should I use node's `fs.mkdir()` function or can I just give it the path as a string even though the sub-directory does not exist yet?

Also, is it a requirement to use `path.join()` over concatenating strings to create a the destination path?

```
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
const metadata = {
  contentType: contentType,
};
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: tempFilePath,
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Cloud Functions runtime, /tmp already exists, so there is no need to try to create it before you write a file there.  If you want to create a subdirectory under /tmp, you will have to create that on your own (and delete it when your function is done).

Comment: Yeah but how do you create it?

Comment: How did you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for create directory inside `/tmp`

```
  import fs = require("fs");
  ...

  const tempOutputDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "new_folder");    
  if (!fs.existsSync(tempOutputDir)) {
    console.log("new_folder doesnt exist, create new one..");
    fs.mkdirSync(tempOutputDir);
  }
```